# is it possible to detect operating system in c++?

Tags: c++, perl, operating-system

I am using CentOS, and trying to convert perl code into C++. in perl we can detect operating system using

```
$^O or we can print: print "S^O";
o/p: linux
```

We have any function in C++, which will do this work. 
thanks in advance.

Comment: The problem is that getting to know the operating system name is, well, operating system dependent. On POSIX systems (like OSX or Linux) you can use the [`uname`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/uname.2.html) system call. There is a similar system call for Windows.

Comment: Do you want to detect the OS at compile time or at run time?

Comment: Note that `$^O` is the platform on which the perl executable was *built*. That is usually, but not always, the platform where it is being *run*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Joachim Pileborg Thanks for the suggestion... for uname system call ... from following code i can get system informations.

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <errno.h>
 #include <sys/utsname.h>

int main(void) {

 struct utsname buffer;

 errno = 0;
 if (uname(&buffer) != 0) {
  perror("uname");
  exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

 printf("system name = %s\n", buffer.sysname);
 printf("node name   = %s\n", buffer.nodename);
 printf("release     = %s\n", buffer.release);
 printf("version     = %s\n", buffer.version);
 printf("machine     = %s\n", buffer.machine);

 return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Whether `sys/utsname.h` will be available is ... system dependent.

Comment: @erdarshp: If you only want to support your own system, why don't you just hardcode the OS name. Or is it the *version* that you're primarily interested in?

Answer (score 0):

There are two general ways:

- OS sniffing via macros
  E.g. if `WIN32` is defined then you're on Windows.
- Header search paths.
  A C++ program has to be built for each platform. Just define header search paths so that the relevant header versions for the platform are found.

For OS sniffing check out [the macro list at SourceForge](http://sourceforge.net/p/predef/wiki/OperatingSystems/) (AFAIK there's only one such project there).